# How to make this specific sphere?

Tags: mesh

How can I make this beautiful specific sphere?

[image: specific sphere]

Is there an add-on or something?

Comment: It's very hard to see what you're talking about from the photo. You mean a low-poly sphere? Make a cylinder with 5 sides, add a loop cut in the center and scale it outwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a cube, in edit mode add a subdivision and then select the vertices in the center of each side and scale outward slightly. Then select the corner vertices and scale inward slightly.[image]

Comment: actually it's simpler to just add a subdivision surface modifier to the cube and apply it

Comment: It's the same result in the end either way

Comment: Thanks guys for your answers, I can't upvote you but thanks